# Silex , mongo DB and updating a Document , Unique Constraint validation doesnt work properly

Tags: validation, mongodb, symfony, silex

I'm testing [silex](/questions/tagged/silex), [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) and Form validation. And I run into a validation issue when using MongoDB ODM and a before middelware , wether it is security related or not.

I'm given a document and have added an Unique constraint on a field of the document.

If the document is not requested before the validation actually executes, everything works fine.

Let's say I have a before middleware that requests the document before the controller  with validation is executed. In that case the unique constraint does not work properly and displays an error message saying **This value is already used**. But it should not since the value used is unique to the object that is validated.

**To sum up**, the issue is, when validating a document with an Unique Constraint on a field, if the document is requested through the document manager (with no modification performed on the document) before the validation code is actually executed, it seems the Unique constraint does not work properly.

I'm going to set up a test case but in the mean time, here is an example of how I set up the validation on the document; if anybody has come across the issue please let me know.

```
namespace Document;
//use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;


use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="blog_post")
 */
class Post
{

    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     * 
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     * @ODM\UniqueIndex
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @ODM\Date
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Document\User",cascade="update,merge",inversedBy="posts")
     */
    protected $user;

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getBody() {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->user->addPost($this);
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadatas) {
        $metadatas->addPropertyConstraint("body", new Length(array('min'=>10,'max'=>1000)));
        $metadatas->addPropertyConstraint("title", new Length(array('min'=>5,'max'=>255)));
        $metadatas->addConstraint(new Unique(array('fields'  => 'title')));
    }

}
```

The app is in [this Github repository](https://github.com/Mparaiso/doctrineodmserviceprovider/tree/master/demo/mongodb/blog). (work in progress):

**Edit 1**: An example of a before middleware that would trigger the erratic behavior of the Unique Constraint (in `demo/mongoddb/blog/app/Config.php` file in the repo linked)  :

```
$app['must_be_post_owner'] = $app->protect(function(Request $req)use($app) {
                $postId = $req->attributes->get('id');
                $user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();
                $post = $app['odm.dm']->getRepository('Document\Post')->findOneBy(array('id' => $postId));
                if ($post->getUser() !== $user) {
                    $app['logger']->alert("Access denied for user $user to post with id $postId ");
                    $app->abort(500, 'You cant access this resource !');
                }
            }
    );
```

**Edit 2**: I tried to debug the Symfony/Doctrine-Bridge UniqueEntityValidator class with XDebug but I get socket errors every time there is a MongoDB related function executed during step debugging.